# Double Login ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Has anyone ever experienced the following situation in .net with forms authentication?

- User logs into system.
- User is allowed into the "default" page inside of the directory
  controlled by forms authentication.
- User attempts to click on another link also inside of the directory
  controlled by forms authentication.
- Application redirects them to the login page again as if they hadn't
  already logged in.

It's an ASP.net 3.5 website application, running IIS7, hosted in a Server Farm with just 2 servers.  Authentication is managed by cookies on the users system and server affinity is turned on...so "technically" they should arrive at one of the two servers and stay there.

Thanks for any help/insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a server farm you're load balanced (I assume) so you have no idea what server you're going to end up on, when working in a farm with forms authentication you need to ensure that the encrypt / decrypt keys are the same or the cookie created on server A can not be read by server B. Here's an example of a machine key that can be added to the web config to ensure cookies can be read in the farm:

```
<machineKey decryption="AES" decryptionKey="3B9E54DB3BB7DC57FF7CFBD8570B7AA21CD71BF63C6A9B48,IsolateApps" validationKey="3A74D6A6BA4C0771232C24FEFF997337F8B9542C255F5EA8EF214918A320362528EDA984A5AA8D0C24FDF50A062718932293496572248668C30DC3FAE2BDA183,IsolateApps" />
```